# SAPUI5 Time sheet calculator with a calendar

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm trying to build a custom time sheet calculator fiori app with a calendar on top that displays 2 weeks at a time and a table below that calculate the number of hours and the amount payed...
I'm trying to figure out the best approach to do this?...
if anyone has a good example to follow or some guidance to do this please help.

Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what exactly are you looking for? which sapui5-controls to use?

Comment: I'm trying to build something like this:

Comment: Sorry I couldn't attach the picture... but I'm trying to insert a calender in a table and calculate the number of hours and the cost associated with them.

Comment: might seem to be clear for you, its not for me. can you show some pictures or anything?

Comment: I need 10 more posts to be able to post an image here..but I can try emailing you the picture...Thanks for help.